# Why doesn't Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus's QueueClient drop back to HTTPS?

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azureservicebus

I've been struggling with some Azure ServiceBus communication issues and after some time I pinned it down to my company's web proxy.  However from what I've researched, it should be working despite that proxy.

My expectation is that the new ServiceBus library should also be dropping back to HTTPS ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#protocols)) but it isn't appearing to do so.  There's a number of GitHub issues on this previously not working, but they all state that it should be fixed in [1.1.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/102) and I'm using 3.0.2 (installed from NuGet with all dependencies last week).

Is there something explicit I need to do to enable it, or is there some further change in behaviour between the two implementations?

Synopsis (links to sample code I was using, and port monitoring done via Process Monitor):

- Using the old [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient](https://github.com/robotechredmond/Azure-PowerShell-Snippets/blob/master/Service%20Bus%20-%20Send%20to%20Queue.ps1) works.  I can see connections to our web proxy on port 8080.
- Using the new [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.QueueClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) does not work.  This attempts to connect to an IP address on port 5671 and results in a TimeOutException.  Moving outside of our company's intranet causes the sample code to start working.

It's left me scratching my head as to why the former works but the latter doesn't.

Comment: Have a look at [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764285/cannot-connect-to-azure-servicebus-with-microsoft-azure-servicebus)

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  I've voted to close my question rather than deleted because I'd search high and low but that question never made it to Google or StackOverflow results.